# how to edit such long code/error blocks?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, formatting

[Accessing fileURL from My Photo Stream says "Operation not permitted"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367602/accessing-fileurl-from-my-photo-stream-says-operation-not-permitted)

This question has a terrible formatting. It is not suitable for:

- Text: as it is code(in some form) and such texts are best understood in monospaced texts + is has new lines which are not introduced in plain text.
- ``` Code as some of the text flows out long inside the scroll-bar.
- Quote: it brings back the text, though code part is highlighted and it is a form of quote (of the error) too.
- Single line code: fixes scrollbar  and monospace, But introduces whitespace and stray grey color at the end of some lines.

**How can this question be nicely formatted or should this be edited at all?**

text for quick experimentation:

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData* imageData, __unused NSString *dataUTI, __unused UIImageOrientation orientation, __unused NSDictionary* info)

Printing description of info:
{
    PHImageFileDataKey =  bufferLength=638976 dataLength=635368;
    PHImageFileOrientationKey = 0;
    PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey = "b96d223e9c27f2539310dc2a6759c09510c8d957;00;00000000;00000000;00000000;000000000000001a;com.apple.app-sandbox.read;01;01000003;00000000001fc7e3;01;/private/var/mobile/Media/PhotoStreamsData/11__676__94/100APPLE/IMG_____.JPG";
    PHImageFileURLKey = "file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoStreamsData/11__676__94/100APPLE/IMG____.JPG";
    PHImageFileUTIKey = "public.jpeg";
    PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 9999;
    PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 0;
    PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 0;
    PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey = 0;
    PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 9999;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is off-topic anyway there is no need to even try to format it correctly :-) But if it would have been on-topic I would expect

- the code part to be pre-formatted with line breaks and then just formatted as code
- the data dumps to be pre-formatted with one attribute per line and again formatted as code

But overall it's question which even on SO will require some heavy editing not only for the formatting..

As a more general answer see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) which covers this quite thoroughly, including how to include hints to get proper source code coloring. Formatting needs to be done by the OP though in any case.